# Conditional OneToOne in Django

Tags: python, database, django, rdbms

Currently I have 4 classes in a model:

```
    User(models.Model):
    ....
        class Meta:
            abstract=True
    Sender(User):
    ....
    Owner(User):
    ....
    Report(models.Model):
         sender = models.OneToOneField(Sender)
         owner = models.OneToOneField(Owner)
```

The Sender/Owner extends the abstract base class User. I need a one to one relationship between a sender, a report, and an owner.

The problem is that I cannot create the Sender or Owner models because they have no differences in their fields (all the data they need is created in the abstract User model, and I created the subclasses for ease of representation). The solution I have come up with is this:

```
    User(models.Model):
    ....
        user_type = models.CharField(max_length=200)

        class Meta:
            abstract=True

    Report(models.Model):
         sender = models.OneToOne(User)
         owner = models.OneToOne(User)
```

However I want to ensure that there is one sender and one owner per report. Is there a way to specify that the User MUST have a user_type of 'sender' or something along those lines? Or is there a better solution to this in general?

Comment: could django - polymorhpic help you create your models/relationships?
https://github.com/chrisglass/django_polymorphic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a veteran user, so forgive me if I'm in the wrong here, but I don't know that it's good practice to define a new model called User when `django.contrib.auth.models` provides a base user model also named User. It seems to me like this would set you up for potential conflicts.

Since you want to have two different "types" of user, I would use the old approach of linking back from a related model.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models


class Sender(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='sender')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)


class Owner(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='owner')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Say you create a new User with `id=1`, then create a new Sender called `s` keyed to that User. Remember, `s` is the Sender object, not the User object.

```
>>s.user
<user: username> #can vary with your own unicode definitions
>>s.user.id
1
>>print hasattr(s.user, 'sender')
True
>>print hasattr(s.user, 'owner')
False
>>print s.is_active
True
>>u = User.objects.get(id=1)
>>u.sender
<Sender: username> #again, what actually displays is controlled by your own 'def __unicode__'
>>print u.sender.is_active
True
>>print hasattr(u, 'sender')
True
>>print hasattr(u, 'owner')
False
```

Then for the report model:

```
class Report(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(Sender, related_name='report_sender')
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner, related_name='report_owner')
```

Edit to answer your other question: how do you make sure a User has only a Sender or Owner model, but not both?

I don't know how to accomplish that on the model level. In practice, the easiest way I can think of to prevent this from being an issue would be through some custom form validation when a new Sender/Owner is created. If you're creating a new Sender, as part of validation make sure that the User you're tying it to doesn't already have an Owner model tied to it - and vice versa. Or create both the user and appropriate profile model at the same time.

You could alter your User registration form to have an extra field:

```
class UserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):

    CHOICES = (
        ('s', 'Sender'),
        ('o', 'Owner'),
    )

    type = models.ChoiceField(max_length=2, choices=CHOICES)

    class Meta: ...
```

Then when you're processing the form in your view:

```
...
if form.is_valid():
    u = form.save()
    type = form.cleaned_data['type']
    if type == 's':
        Sender.objects.create(user=u)
    elif type == 'o':
        Owner.objects.create(user=u)
```

(I apologize, but I am not somewhere I can test this. Please let me know if it doesn't work for you.)

Comment: What's the purpose of is_active? Also is there a way to ensure that User only has either a Sender or an Owner?

Comment: It's not necessary beyond allowing you to do the `s.is_active` thing. The extra data field was useful to me for illustrating how the two models relate to each other, but you can leave it out. I will edit a response to your second question into the main answer above.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most straightforward way to resolve this is to override the save() method of the Report model and insert (before a super() call) a validation check to enforce your requirements.